# My guessing game not functioning correctly

Tags: python

It's not selecting the level of difficulty. Did I forget something? For example, I want it to select 3 for hard, which then leads the game to select from 1 to 1000 with 5 tries. and if the user selects 2 for easy they have to guess from 1 to 500 with 10 tries

```
import random


print('What level would you like to play 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard')
print(1,2,3)

number = random.randint(1, 100)
number_of_guesses = 0

print(' Try Guessing a number between 1 and 100:')

while number_of_guesses < 15:
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    guess = int(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if guess == number:
        break
      
while number_of_guesses < 10:
    number = random.randint(1, 500)
    guess = int(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if guess == number:
        break
      
while number_of_guesses < 5:
    number = random.randint(1, 500)
    guess = int(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print('You guessed the number in ' + str(number_of_guesses) + ' tries!')
else:
    print('You did not guess the number, The number was ' + str(number))
```

Comment: You never ask for them to input a choice, and you never check that choice's value and change the flow of program execution in response. Also, please remember a key element of programming: DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When you run your code, what do you get?  The formatting of your code suggests 1) You're not asking any input from the user, 2)  you're going through all three while loops.

Comment: where would i put the user input

Comment: Where you have `print(1, 2, 3)`, put `level = int(input())`.  That'll ask the user for input, convert it to an `int`, and assign it to `level`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the user input for difficulty. Choose maximum guess and highest limit of number based on input as well. Then a single while loop can do the job.

```
import random
difficulty = int(input('What level would you like to play 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard: '))
max_guess = 0
highest_number = 0
if difficulty == 1:
    max_guess = 15
    highest_number = 100
elif difficulty == 2:
    max_guess = 10
    highest_number = 500
elif difficulty == 3:
    max_guess = 15
    highest_number = 100
else:
    print("Wrong choice")


number_of_guesses = 0
number = random.randint(1, highest_number)

while number_of_guesses < max_guess:
    guess = int(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print('You guessed the number in ' + str(number_of_guesses) + ' tries!')
else:
    print('You did not guess the number, The number was ' + str(number))
```

Edit: Sorry previous code had some issues. here is the full code that can work

Comment: thank you i see what you did. What do you mean by my code what part do I add

Comment: Edited to add full executable. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

```
level = input("Print your level here")
if int(level) == 1:
    # set level to 1
if int(level) == 2:
    # set level to 2
if int(level) == 3:
    # set level to 3
```

The problem with your code is that you

1. Don't take user input.
2. Even if you had user input you don't act on it.

You also aren't excepting input for the guess.

Here is a link to learn more on how to use the python input() function
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you did use the input.